# Why don't indirect questions undergo subject-auxiliary inversion, like in languages like Spanish?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion, indirect-question

Just two days ago, I asked a [question about indirect questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/618842/noun-verb-order-in-indirect-questions-compared-with-direct-questions) in Spanish and English.

Usually, when we pose an indirect question in English, we first ask a direct question like this: "Do you know or Can you tell me", and then we say the real question indirectly. But in Spanish, they say two direct questions.

Now, I may have not asked an easy question to comprehend at first. So, one of the guys answered with a question that clears up my doubt on the topic more clearly than with a short question:

"Why don't indirect questions undergo subject-auxiliary inversion?"

So there you have it, my question is: **Why don't we have subject-auxiliary inversion with indirect questions, like Spanish does?**

This is just something I've noticed when learning Spanish and English at the same time.